# HMS application development - I've lost my signing keys for Huawei App Gallery

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery

I've lost all my signing keys for my apps in Huawei! I've reset my computer and forgot to save them somewhere else. Is there any solution for this, in case i want to update my apps which are published in App Gallery ?

Answer (score 0):

It is  not recommend that you change the keystore/signature because your app will be rejected during the review process.

If a  keystore/signature change is necessary for you since you have lost it, you can leave a note saying “Agree to ignore  keystore/signature difference” in the Notes column of the Version information page when you submit the app for review.
However, errors may occur during app updates if you decide to modify the appkeystore/signature, and users may have to reinstall the app before they can use the new version.